# Where I can find MariaDB protocol document that different from MySQL

Tags: mysql, protocols, replication, mariadb

MySQL support GTID at 5.6, MariaDB support at 10.0.2, but MariaDB is MySQL 5.5.5 compatible.

So, the GTID replication protocol is different from MySQL's replication.

Here is something that I can find out

- GTID format is different

  - MySQL:

    - UUID SET

      - `3E11FA47-71CA-11E1-9E33-C80AA9429562:23`
      - `server_uuid:interval`
    - GTID SET

      - `uuid_set[, uuid_set] ... | ''`
  - MariaDB

    - `0-3306-123`
    - `DomainID-ServerID-Sequence`
- How to start GTID replication

  - MySQL

    - Use COM_BINLOG_DUMP_GTID
  - MariaDB

    - `SET @mariadb_slave_capability = 4;-- GTID capability`
    - `SET @slave_connect_state = '0-3311-90';-- GTID`
    - `Send REGISTER_SLAVE`

But the response packet is still not the same.So, is there any document about these different ?

### Reference

- MySQL

  - [Replication with Global Transaction Identifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-gtids.html)
  - [COM_BINLOG_DUMP_GTID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/com-binlog-dump-gtid.html)
- MariaDB

  - [Global Transaction ID](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/global-transaction-id/)
  - [MariaDB 1- GTID explain](https://mariadb.com/blog/mariadb-10-gtid-explained)
  - [Enabling GTIDs for server replication in MariaDB 10.0](https://mariadb.com/blog/enabling-gtids-server-replication-mariadb-100)

Comment: All I was able to find is [MariaDB 10.0 vs. MySQL 5.5 and 5.6 incompatibilities](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/) that says `MariaDB GTID is not compatible with MySQL 5.6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find the document in [code](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.1/sql/log_event.h#L999), described how.

Thanks to @zedfoxus, I found [issue MDEV-26](https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-26) described internal.

According to above, I implement maria GTID mode replication [here](https://github.com/shyiko/mysql-binlog-connector-java/pull/50)